# How i can create a function for reading structure from a test.txt

Tags: c, file, structure, fread

How i can create a function for reading structure from a test.txt. I have a good works code in main, but i need to carry out it from main(). How combine (struct student PI1[N] and (fread() or fgets() or fwrite()));

```
struct student {
    char surname[50];
    char name[50];
    char dayBirth[50];
    int mark;
};

struct student PI1[N];
```

```
int main()
{
    
    int counter = 0;
    char str[50];
    const char s[2] = " ";
    char* token;
    FILE* ptr;
    int i = 0;

    ptr = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if (NULL == ptr) {
        printf("file can't be opened \n");
    }
    char* tmp;
    int Itmp;

    while (fgets(str, 50, ptr) != NULL) {
        token = strtok(str, s);
        strcpy(PI1[i].surname, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, s);
        strcpy(PI1[i].name, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, s);
        strcpy(PI1[i].dayBirth, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, s);
        Itmp = atoi(token);
        PI1[i].mark = Itmp;
        i++;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: void readFile(struct student *PI1, int counter)

Comment: `readFile(&PI1, counter)` - **doesn't work**

Comment: `void readFile(struct student *PI1, int counter)` is ok, now put `struct student PI1[N];` inside `main` and call `readFile(PI1, N);` without the ampersand, the loop should be something like `while ((counter < N) && fgets(str, 50, ptr) != NULL) { ` to not write outside of the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than "can create a function for reading structure from a test.txt", start with a function to convert a *string* from `fgets()` into a `struct`.  Then call it as needed.

Use `sprintf()` and `" %n"` to detect complete scan with no extra text.

```
// Return success flag
bool string_to_student(struct student *stu, const char *s) {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(s, "%49s%49s%49s%d %n", stu->surname, stu->name,
      stu->dayBirth, &stu->mark, &n);
  return n > 0 && s[n] == '\0';
}
```

Use

```
while (i < N && fgets(str, sizeof str, ptr) && 
    string_to_student(&PI1[i], str)) {
  i++;
}
counter = i;
```